# TCSH: convert a sed output to a expr sum

Tags: shell, awk, sed, csh, expr

Hi im having troubles with the following code:

```
#|/bin/tcsh
TOTALMOS=`grep -v "Last MO:" x.log | grep "Total: .* MOs" | grep "Total: .* MOs" | awk '{ print $2 }' | tr '\n' ' ' | awk '{ print $1 }'`
RADIONO=`grep -n "get radio no" x.log | cut -f1 -d:`
RADIONO2=`expr "$RADIONO" + 6`
RADIONO3=`expr "$RADIONO2" + "$TOTALMOS"`
SED=`sed -n ''$RADIONO2','$RADIONO3'p' x.log | awk '{ print $3 }' | tr '\n' '  '`
echo "$SED"
```

The output is the following:

```
5 8 2 4 0 10 6 11 1 3 1 9
```

Pease note: there are two breaks at the end of the script being `"...1 9__"`

Well what i really want it is SUM all the numbers excluding the final breaks that idk where they come from. My first thought was substitute the newlines with "+" and then make it work with expr but it does not work at all...

Please any advice?

Thanks in advance!

Best Regards.

Comment: Never write [t]csh scripts - Google "csh why not". Edit your question to show a representative test case with sample input and output so we can help you write a concise awk script to do everything you are trying to do with that mush of shell, awk and a dozen other tools and pipelines.

Comment: Do not use the `sh` tag for shells incompatible with the POSIX sh standard!

Comment: Why not work with csh? They say its very like C and i wanted to start with some lenguage that will work for me in the future, im just a beginner. But i want to learn all related with linux to improve my skills at work!

Comment: Do you really want to know?: [Top ten reason to not use csh](http://www.grymoire.com/unix/CshTop10.txt)

Answer (score 1):

awk to the rescue

```
$ echo "1 2 3 4 5 6 7    " | awk -vRS=" " '{sum+=$0} END{print sum}'
28
$ echo "1 2 3 4 5 6 7    " | awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) sum+=i; print sum}'                    
28
```

these two will scripts both sum up the numbers ignoring the trailing blanks if it's what you mean by "two breaks at the end of the script".

Comment: Thanks!! I'll try it tomorrow at work, idk why some commands don't work on Ubuntu 14 and work at my workplace, they use unix buy an old build i think. I meant just what you said i wanted to ignore the trailing blanks, (i don't know why they show up...) but my english is a little bit but sorry. Thanks again